# Error when creating jar file: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, executable-jar, noclassdeffounderror

My code compiles correctly in Eclipse, as well as runs. Before I added a piece of code I could also successfully make a jar file by doing:

```
jar cvfm Manifest.txt <Classes>
```

then I added this to my code in the constructor:

```
addWindowFocusListener(new WindowAdapter() {
public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
    JFrame window = (JFrame) e.getSource();
            window.toBack();
}});
```

When I try to create a new jar file and run it, I receive the NoClassDefError with the error line pointing to that code. To be specific, I got this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: BinaryClock$1
at BinaryClock.<init>(BinaryClock.java:55)
```

BinaryClock being my main class and line 55 being the first line of the code from above. I don't understand why it makes BinaryClock$1, then gives me the error on it.

If more code or information is needed, let me know. I didn't want to paste my entire source code if it wasn't needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `BinaryClock$1.class` file will contain the anonymous inner class created for your `WindowAdapter` in the code you've shown. You should include that file in the jar file.

Basically, you should build into a clean directory, and include *everything* in that directory in your jar file. Don't try to be selective about it - if a file is being produced by the compiler, there's a good reason for it.

Comment: Alright. But, that Class isn't in the directory to start with. How would I specify it?

Comment: @Troncoso: If you've built BinaryClock.java, it will be there somewhere. You haven't really told us how you're building your code, but it will be wherever the compiler is writing the files. If you're then copying *some* of the output files to another directory before creating the jar file, you need to change that part of your build process.

Comment: Ahh. I found it. I let Eclipse build it, but because I didn't know about the BinaryClock$1.class, I'd delete to see if that made a difference. Eclipse wouldn't rebuild it automatically, so I told it to, the file came back, I created a new jar and it worked just fine. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can create jar files from Eclipse directly. Right click on your project in Package Explorer -> Export... -> Java -> JAR file. This is very convenient because it considers all your settings on the project including the classpath and lets you specify a ton of additional options. Moreover, you can save it in an Ant file which can be run with the External tools.
More info here: http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-33.htm